# How to convert list to queue to achieve FIFO

Tags: java, list, queue

Consider:

```
public List<Place> getAllInactivePlaces() {

    return this.placeDAO.findAllUnApprovedList();
}
```

The method I have shown above is to find all places. I need to convert *Queue* to get a FIFO.

Something like this:

```
Queue<Place>placeQueue = getAllInactivePlaces();
```

Comment: That means that `placeDAO.findAllUnApprovedList()` will need to change its return type to match that of a `Queue`.

Comment: first get list of places. then put all places into a queue. return that queue.

Comment: @user3318622, demanding an answer isn't going to get you much help.  You need to demonstrate that you've tried to find a solution yourself first.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming that you currently have a list which is not a queue (like an `ArrayList`). Further assuming that you cannot pick a data structure appropriate to your use case to start with:

```
Queue<Place> queue = new LinkedList<>(yourList);
```

Comment: @Thufir It works for me.  Are you sure that you aren't trying to cast an ArrayList to a Queue?  You have to actually copy it to a LinkedList (which implements the Queue interface) first.

Comment: ah, that's probably what it was.

Answer (score 0):

"Achieve FIFO" is less a question of the data structure being used, but more about the code that puts in/pulls out data from that structure.

You need to update that calling code to work with the [Queue interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) instead of a List.

Comment: it gives java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Queue

Comment: Yes, you need to update the code to not use List and ArrayList anymore.