# Convert Array to Queue

Tags: java, data-structures

I wish to create a Queue (or Stack) in java using all the elements from an array.
Is there some 'nice' way of doing this, i.e in one line without a loop over the array?

Comment: suppose this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485944/how-to-convert-list-to-queue-to-achieve-fifo) may be helpful to get started.

Comment: View this post for help in the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153502/convert-queue-into-long-array

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work. yourArray is the input array. Substitute *Object* for whatever data type you're dealing with.

```
Queue<Object> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
```

Comment: It worked with Queues but not Stacks, which is good enough for me

Comment: Usually ArrayDeque is better than LinkedList though.

Answer (score 3):

For stacks, you should create a vector object, because stack extends Vector class.

```
Stack<Object> stack = (Stack<Object>) new Vector(Arrays.asList(theArray));
```